# setIconImage in java not working

Tags: java

I am trying to make my setIconImage() to get work but sad to say that I failed to get work, so now I need your help with you guys...

here is my code

```
form.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("inventory/images/image-background-5.jpg")).getImage());
```

here is my image path

[image]

but I don't know whats the problem why I got this error

[image]

Comment: Add a slash in front of the path: `().getResource("/inventory/images/image-Background`

Comment: yes. thank you. I missed this symbol.

Comment: 1 more thing. the error is gone but still the image won't display.

Comment: Maybe a wrong Format. Hard to say

Comment: haaha. my bad again, sorry.. I thought the setIconImage() change the background of the frame, but it will change the icon image on the left side of the frame,,. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You have a [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), which is due to the fact that you try to call `getImage()` of a `null` object. You have a `null` object since `getResource("inventory/images/image-background-5.jpg")` returned `null`. As discussed in the comment section, you needed to use a / at the start of the path.